# I am creating a table in pgweb Heroku, and get this error "ERROR: pq: syntax error at or near "(""

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table

Here is my exact query

```
CREATE Table Publisher 
(Publisher_Id     Int primary key not null,
Name          varchar(20) not null,  
Address       varchar(50) not null,
Phone         Int(10),
Isbn          varchar(13) references books (Isbn) not null
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Int(10)` should be `int` [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html)

Comment: Phone numbers aren't ints. You don't do arithmetic with them. char(10) makes more sense.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson [don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Comment: Yeah, I've heard that. Is it deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

datatype `int` does not take a length. So:

```
create table publisher (
    publisher_id  int primary key,
    name          varchar(20) not null,  
    address       varchar(50) not null,
    phone         int,
    isbn          varchar(13) references books (isbn) not null
);
```

Notes:

- `not null` is redondant on a primary key column
- `int` does not seem like a good pick for a phone number; you would typically need to store leading `0`s, or allow special characters such as `+` or `()` - `int` cannot do that. A string datatype would probably be a better pick

Comment: Thank You so much! now i can continue with my project